# Are Functions Defaults Values Considered Assignments to Parameters in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering if this is considered an assignment in Python or not

```
def func(a,b,c=10): return a+b+c
```

Is `c = 10` syntax assigns 10 to the argument **c** here ?

Comment: What do you want to know? The parameter `c` has the value `10` if none is given when `func` is called. The `=` is a default parameter definition.

Comment: What do you mean by assignment? Some reasonable interpretations include "parsed as an assignment by the parser", "treated like a (conditional) assignment at the start of the function body", "makes the variable local" and each of those leads to a different answer.

Comment: I meant "parsed as an assignment by the parser"

Comment: It's an assignment in the generic sense (providing a value for a name at some point), but it's not parsed as an assignment statement as defined in the Python grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is `c = 10` syntax assigns 10 to the argument c here ?

Not necessarily. If the function is called `func(1,2,3)` then 10 is not assigned to `c`. That's the whole point of a *default* argument value, it's used only if not specified by the caller.

Assuming that the caller doesn't specify a value, then the default is assigned to `c` in the same sense that the specified arguments are assigned to `a` and `b`.

However, this is not an "assignment statement", so there are facts about assignment statements that aren't true of this (probably the most important difference, although it doesn't matter in this example of `10`, is that the right hand side of this isn't evaluated each time, whereas the right hand side of an assignment statement is evaluated each time it's executed). So in the context of talking about "assignments" meaning "assignment statements", it wouldn't be considered an assignment.